# Conditional validation with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, conditional-statements

I have a form with a number of radio button options, all are required.

However I want to add an extra validation on one selection of radio buttons.

For example:

If a value selected equals "Brown" further validation is then needed only on this colour, such as

```
input:radio[name='radTypeJoint']:checked").val() == 'Shear' 
&& 
input:radio[name='radSubstrate']:checked").val() == 'Masonry to Masonry'

return false;
```

Any ideas, many thanks Adam

I've now got it to this:

```
radShade: { required: function(element) {  
                if (($("input:radio[name='radShade']:checked").val() == 'Brown') && ($("input:radio[name='radGeographical']:checked").val() == 'South Facing') || ($("input:radio[name='radShade']:checked").val() == 'Brown') && ($("input:radio[name='radGeographical']:checked").val() == 'West Facing') || ($("input:radio[name='radShade']:checked").val() == 'Brown') && ($("input:radio[name='radMovement']:checked").val() != 'Increase of 12 of minimum joint width') || ($("input:radio[name='radShade']:checked").val() == 'Brown') && ($("input:radio[name='radStories']:checked").val() != 'Less than 3') || ($("input:radio[name='radShade']:checked").val() == 'Brown') && ($("input:radio[name='radSubstrate']:checked").val() != 'Masonry to Masonry') || ($("input:radio[name='radShade']:checked").val() == 'Brown') && ($("input:radio[name='radElements']:checked").val() == 'Window') || ($("input:radio[name='radShade']:checked").val() == 'Brown') && ($("input:radio[name='radTypeJoint']:checked").val() == 'Fillet')) {
                alert("This shade is not available with your current selections");
                return false;
                };
            }
```

but the form is still be submitted even if I but return true or return false.

Comment: i am  not getting your question....i think you have already written answer of your question...

Comment: I'm after the right syntax as I'm not getting any error or result returned. I sort of know I'm on the right track but it just nor happening for me.

Comment: why you have written return false?

Comment: Looking further into this I'm just getting more frustrated. I have this section that is required radShade: { required: true } then depending if the value of this section is 'brown' I need to do further validation on the results against this colour selected. Any ideas please :-(

Answer (score 1):

**Check it Out:**

**HTML:**

```
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="brown" id="all" runat="server" class="cssRadio"/>
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="black" id="Radio1" runat="server" class="cssRadio"/>
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="red" id="Radio3" runat="server" class="cssRadio"/>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(".cssRadio").click(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="brown")
    {
        //here u get the object of clicked radion button now do your validation
        alert($(this).val());
    }
    if($(this).val()=="black")
    {
        //here u get the object of clicked radion button now do your validation
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: @Vivek: as per i understand from this question is that Adam want to apply further validation on the selected radio button.so in this way he will get object of the selected radio button and do further validation.

Comment: Looking further into this I'm just getting more frustrated. I have this section that is required radShade: { required: true } then depending if the value of this section is 'brown' I need to do further validation on the results against this colour selected. Any ideas please :-( –

Comment: did u mean that after displaying alert("This shade is not available with your current selections") pop up the form is submitting even if u have written return false after this??